# Python 2D array and loop

Tags: python, arrays, memory, garbage-collection

I'm new to Python and am attempting to set up a script to check the status of specific wifi connected IOT devices on my local network.

Essentially, the script takes the mac hardware IDs I want to check; pings the network to trigger ARPs's; searches the response to arp-a for the relevant mac ID's which are printed with the date and time if located successfully.

Two questions-
1) At the moment I am just searching this for 2 mac addresses however going forward it's more likely to be 20.  How can I amend my detect_mac function to take a two-dimensional array (or similar) and loop through the results to avoid having to repeat the `if any(address in str_output for address in input_address_list1):` line 20 times.

2) If I leave this script running constantly (it has a 10 minute timer between runs) will this python eventually crash? Is there some sort of garbage collection, log overflow etc I would need to consider?

```
import pdb, os
import subprocess
import re
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

lower=1
upper=25
MAC_address_list1 = ["58:e2:zz:xx:28:d7"]
MAC_address_list2 = ["08:05:xx:zz:75:c5"]
MAC_address_list3 = ["##:##:##:##:##:##"]
MAC_address_list4 = ["##:##:##:##:##:##"]
p = {}

# Get The Current Date and Time
def getdatetime():
    import time
    return time.strftime("%H:%M %d/%m/%Y ")

def detect_mac(input_address_list1, input_address_list2):
    # Assign list of devices on the network to "output"
    output = subprocess.check_output("arp -a", shell=True)

    str_output = output.decode("utf-8")   

    if any(address in str_output for address in input_address_list1):
        print(getdatetime() + str(input_address_list1))

    if any(address in str_output for address in input_address_list2):
        print(getdatetime() + str(input_address_list2))

    #sleep 10 minutes
    time.sleep(600)
    return True


while 1:
    # ping all IPs in range to make ARP available
    for i in range(lower,upper):
        ip = "192.168.1.%d" % i
        p[ip] = Popen(['ping', '-n', '-w5', '-c3', ip], stdout=DEVNULL)

    detect_mac(MAC_address_list1, MAC_address_list2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can certainly answer point 1):

```
import pdb, s
import subprocess
import re
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL

lower=1
upper=25
MAC_address_list1 = ["58:e2:zz:xx:28:d7"]
MAC_address_list2 = ["08:05:xx:zz:75:c5"]
MAC_address_list3 = ["##:##:##:##:##:##"]
MAC_address_list4 = ["##:##:##:##:##:##"]

MAC_addresses = ([MAC_address_list1],[MAC_address_list2])

[...]

def detect_mac(input_address_list):
  # Assign list of devices on the network to "output"
  output = subprocess.check_output("arp -a", shell=True)

  str_output = output.decode("utf-8")   

  for address_list in input_address_list:

    if any(address[0] in str_output for address in address_list):
        print(getdatetime() + str(address_list))



  #sleep 10 minutes
  time.sleep(600)
  return True
```

Comment: The Two snippets should do the same. Only difference is that you can add more lists into MAC_addresses.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I think you're answer looks good but I get this type error-
 if any(address in str_output for address in input_address_list):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list.

Comment: Do you call `detect_mac(MAC_addresses)` like this ?

Comment: Yes. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/detect_macs1.py", line 43, in <module>
    detect_mac(MAC_addresses)
  File "/home/pi/Documents/detect_macs1.py", line 29, in detect_mac
    if any(address in str_output for address in address_list):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/detect_macs1.py", line 29, in <genexpr>
    if any(address in str_output for address in address_list):
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`

Comment: I think i fixed it. You should consider using just strings instead of 1d-1length array for you single addresses:  MAC_address_list1 = ("58:e2:zz:xx:28:d7")